# mount ramfs as user

Tags: filesystems, permissions, mount, fstab

My fstab entry:

```
none    /home/jreinhart/ramdisk    ramfs    defaults,user   0 0
```

The directory *before* mounting:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 jreinhart jreinhart  4096  Oct 17 11:31 ramdisk
```

The directory after `mount ramdisk`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     jreinhart  4096  Oct 17 11:31 ramdisk
```

So, you can see the problem. Once I mount, the *owner* changes to root, and the group permissions go to `r-x` so I cannot use this ramdisk.  What gives?

I'm trying to do this without having to `su`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Using `mode=777` instead of `umask=777` as an option seems to work (Ubuntu 15.10).

Comment: This is the sole right answer. So the OP's `fstab` entry may look like this: `none    /home/jreinhart/ramdisk    ramfs    user,noauto,size=1024M,mode=0770    0 0`. I removed `defaults` since it  somewhat contradicts to `user` (it implies plenty of other options) and tuned `mode` to a more safe world-non-readable `0770` mask (so only `root` and `jreinhart` may read and write to this).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is Linux, you could also use `tmpfs` [(see here for differences, i.e., why it might be advisable to use `tmpfs`)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt), [which is explained here](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0.4/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt) and (see link) supports the options `mode`, `gid` and `uid`.  There's the following paragraph in `tmpfs.txt` which might also be relevant:

```
These options do not have any effect on remount. You can change these
parameters with chmod(1), chown(1) and chgrp(1) on a mounted filesystem.
```

So maybe a `sudo chown ...` is still needed (I guess not, but I'm not quite sure about this, sorry.)

Comment: I should have mentioned it, but I can't use tmpfs.  tmpfs can be paged out to disk, which I need to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid sudo you could use the automounter here (service autofs). Look for executable automount-maps. There you can script anything you want before, during and after the actual mount.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally somewhat dangerous to give non-root acces to a ramfs mount, since a (malicious/ignorant) user could put enough data into it to fill all available system RAM. Like others above have mentioned, something like tmpfs or even a ram disk might be more desirable for non-root use. (sr_'s post has some really good reads.)

Comment: Incorrect, ramfs has a max size option

Comment: @BryanHunt source? Because I read this everywhere. "A ramfs derivative called tmpfs was created to add size limits"

Answer (score -1):

After you mount the ramdisk, `/home/jreinhart/ramdisk` becomes the root of the mounted filesystem. Apparently this directory is owned by root. Change it (and any other relevant file on the ramdisk) once and for all to be owned by `jreinhart`.

You may have seen a different behavior for filesystems like vfat. On filesystems that have no notion of ownership, the filesystem driver tries to come up with sensible fake ownership, generally making every file owned by the user who mounted the filesystem. Filesystems like `ramfs` that provide normal unix permissions expose them directly.

Comment: Except that it's not "once and for all" as the ramfs contents are lost when it is unmounted. OP probably wants the permissions to persist across reboots, which is why he is giving us an fstab entry to look at.