# mount changes directory permissions even with umask=777

Tags: permissions, mount, umask

My `/ramfs` directory ceases to become writable to non-root users after it is mounted with a ramfs partition

```
sudo su
mkdir /ramfs
chmod 777 /ramfs
mount -t ramfs -o size=20m,umask=777 ramfs /ramfs
ls -l / | grep ramfs
```

This outputs

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root        0 Nov 20 13:56 ramfs
```

Note that the permissions have changed.

`mount | grep ramfs` shows

```
ramfs on /ramfs type ramfs (rw,relatime,size=20m,umask=777)
```

What is the correct a) mount command, and b) fstab entry to make this directory be mounted with `777` permissions?

Comment: duplicate http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22777/mount-ramfs-as-user

Comment: Thanks. I guess that is the same question, although it doesn't have an answer other than to chown separately afterwards.

Comment: no - different problem.

Comment: the same problem. See `man mount`: _"   Mount options for ramfs
       Ramfs is a memory based filesystem.  Mount it and you have it.  Unmount
       it and it is gone.  Present since Linux 2.3.99pre4.  There are no mount
       options."_
The problem is the same: there are no any parameters for ramfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mode=777` instead of `umask=777` as an option seems to work (Ubuntu 15.10).

Comment: ... as long as one uses `tmpfs` rather than `ramfs`.

Comment: I'm using ramfs (non-swapping is a requirement).

Comment: Well well well!  The doco turns out to be a lie and `ramfs` does have mount options.